# Store a generic dictionary in an asp.net profile?

Tags: asp.net, dictionary, generics, profile

Is there any way of storing a generic dictionary object in an asp.net profile? I have tried using this but it still doesn't like it:
http://weblogs.asp.net/pwelter34/default.aspx

Thanks,
Nick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [KeyedCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132438.aspx).  Its a generic dictionary that is serializable to xml.  [There are some limitations, however](http://www.pluralsight.com/community/blogs/craig/archive/2005/10/19/15696.aspx).