# How to store name-value pairs in asp.net profile

Tags: c#, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Store a generic dictionary in an asp.net profile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1277656/store-a-generic-dictionary-in-an-asp-net-profile)

I want to save name-value pairs in a asp.net profile, how can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a class which can hold a keyvalue data like:

```
namespace Samples.AspNet.Profile 
{
    [Serializable]
    public class KeyValue{

        public Dictionary<string, Object> dict= new Dictionary<string, Object>();
    }

}
```

initialize a profile in config of KeyValue type:

```
<profile defaultProvider="AspNetSqlProfileProvider">
  <properties>
    <add name="List" 
      type="Samples.AspNet.Profile.KeyValue" 
      serializeAs="Binary" />
  </properties>
</profile>
```

Now you can add values like this:

```
KeyValue data= new KeyValue ();
data.dict.Add("Contoso","value");
bookCart.CartItems.Add("Microsoft","value2");
Profile.List= data;
```

Comment: thanks for ans, can u explain me how we can use "Profile.List= data;"

Comment: because right now i am using             ProfileBase profile = HttpContext.Current.Profile;
            profile.SetPropertyValue("Images", sc);

Comment: as you see i have added a profile `name=List` which hold data of type `Samples.AspNet.Profile.KeyValue` so we assigning List object of KeyValue or you can try `profile.SetPropertyValue("List", data);`

Comment: yes this formate (profile.SetPropertyValue("List", data);) i am using currently but i want to know that is there a way i can use something like (profile.List = data) instead of (profile.SetPropertyValue("List", data);) to insert data in profile

Comment: yes you can, try and if cant then search about it.

Comment: means getting profile properties in a dropdown list