# class cannot be serializied

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
[Serializable]
    public class KeyValue
    {
        public List<Dictionary<string, string>> pair { get; set; } 
    }
```

Exception comes Keyvalue pair cannot be serialized when i am insert data into profile. Whats the problem?

Comment: AFAIK, ASP .NET uses XML serialization. XmlSerializer can't serialize dictionaries. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1277656/store-a-generic-dictionary-in-an-asp-net-profile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Dictionary` class isn't XML-serializable, but there are a lot of workarounds if you google it. Have a look at [this link](http://weblogs.asp.net/pwelter34/archive/2006/05/03/444961.aspx) for a sample.

Comment: Binary serialization is possible, but XMl serialization is possible with workarounds for hash table and dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using it through WCF you must read the following thread

[How to serialize Dictionary<string, string> through WCF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510185/how-to-serialize-dictionarystring-string-through-wcf)